# Completely replace web.xml with java config (Spring MVC 4 - Tomcat 7/8)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

After searching Google for more than 3 hours, I'm giving up on this.

I have this web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>ar.com.dera.simor.config</param-value>
</context-param>

<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/not_found</location>
</error-page>
```

OK, I did it work just with the servlet, and Spring Security.
But also, I want to configure (in Java) the jsp-config and the error-page.

How can I do this?
This is my WebInitializer class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(WebConfig.class);
        rootContext.scan("ar.com.dera.simor.config");
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = servletContext.addServlet(
                "appServlet", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        appServlet.addMapping("/");
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        servletContext.addFilter("securityFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter utf8Filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        utf8Filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        utf8Filter.setForceEncoding(true);

        return new Filter[] { utf8Filter };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can't. `ServletContext` does not provide any methods to configure errors pages and JSPs from scratch. It does, however, provide a [`getJspConfigDescriptor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getJspConfigDescriptor%28%29) method to get the `<jsp-config>` configuration (readonly).

Comment: Ok, so then, I have to keep web.xml.

Comment: @gaspo53 yeah, you can just use both.